# Laravel: Collection::get causes undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I'm facing problem in fetching data from controller to blade.php file they give an error of undefined variable $plans.

DalyTaskPlanController.php

```php
public function dailyTaskPlan()
    {
        $plans = $this->plans = DailyTaskPlan::select(
        'projects.project_name',
        'daily_task_plans.*',
        'tasks.heading',
        'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('projects', 'daily_task_plans.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
            ->leftJoin('tasks', 'daily_task_plans.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
            ->join('users','daily_task_plans.user_id', '=','users.id')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();
        return view('dailytaskplan::dashboard', compact('plans'));
}
```

in view file they give an error undefined variable

```php
  @foreach ($plans as $plan)
                       
          <tr>
              <td class="pl-25">{{ $plan->project_name }}</td>
              <td class="pl-25">{{ $plan->heading }}</td>
              <td class="pl-25">{{ $plan->date }}</td>
              <td class="pl-25">{{ $plan->estimate_hours }} hrs {{ $plan->estimate_minutes }} mins</td>
              <td class="pl-25">{{ $plan->memo }}</td>
          </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Additional question; how can I merge Laravel module route with project route because when I use module route they override project route?

i tried to make traits folder and give another route for module in other route they working fine. but in main route it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$plans` variable seems to be `NULL`, either provide a default, like:

```
return view('dailytaskplan::dashboard', [
    'plans' => $plans ?? [],
]);
```

Or implement and use `->getOrFail()` which provides better error message.

### Example `getOrFail`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as EloquentBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...
        
        EloquentBuilder::macro('getOrFail', function () {
            return tap($this->get(), function (?Collection $result) {
                if ($result == null || $result->count() < 1) {
                    throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
                        get_class($this->model)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

> **Note** that Laravel has many `OrFail` suffixed helpers, but `getOrFail` did not exist, hence I added one ;-)